# How to create li checkbox using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I am trying to select individual selection and in hidden a input checkbox in an  un-ordered list.

*Issue*: When I click on one it selects all instead of one
I need just like checkbox in list with hidden input checkbox
here is my code shared in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/05fgvg1r/)

```
<ul class="checkbox_list">
    <li>
        ravi
        <p>2343534656 - U44BB387587</p>
        <input type="checkbox" class="input_class_checkbox" id="c1">
    </li>
    <li>
        arvi
        <p>2343534656 - U444BB387587</p>
        <input type="checkbox" class="input_class_checkbox" id="c2">
    </li>
    <li>
        jiva
        <p>2343534656 - 444BB387587</p>
        <input type="checkbox" class="input_class_checkbox" id="c3">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use clicked element context `this` to target correct element:

```
$('.checkbox_list li').on('click',function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('checked').prev().prop('checked',$(this).is('.checked'));
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8cc5t7hr/)**

Comment: not only the class "checked" in ".checkbox_list li",  i want to add the class "checked" in class="class_checkbox"

Comment: @DivyaSharma: `$(this).find('.input_class_checkbox').addClass('checked')`